# String array, failure in writing data in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have string array and I want to copy string in array. It works for while than program has stop working, and I know that problem is in copiyng string. Because if I commented line with copiyng, program works fine.
Here is my code:

```
FILE *fsource = fopen(source, "rb");
char fname[256], **files, mybuf[BUFSIZ];
files = allocate2d(files, count_files);

clear(fname);

reading = fread(mybuf, 1, BUFSIZ, fsource);
while(reading)
{
    for(i = 0; i < reading; i++)
    {
       if(mybuf[i] == 20)
       {
          while(1)
            {
                if(i < reading)
                {
                    if(mybuf[i] == 0)
                    {
                        clear(files[ifiles]);
                        strcat(files[ifiles++], fname); // here is problem :(
                        //append_string(files[ifiles++], fname); // also doesn't work

                        clear(fname);
                        break;
                    }

                    append_char(fname, mybuf[i++]);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
       }

       clear(fname);
    }

    reading = fread(mybuf, 1, BUFSIZ, fsource);
}

char** allocate2d(char **arr, unsigned int size)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    arr = malloc(size * sizeof(char));

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = malloc(256);
    }

return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `allocate2d`:

```
arr = malloc(size * sizeof(char));
```

should be

```
arr = malloc(size * sizeof(char*));
```

since you want to allocate space for `size` pointers.

Also

```
arr[i] = malloc(256);
```

should better be

```
arr[i] = calloc(256, sizeof(char));
```

to ensure that the `strcat` finds a 0 character. (Note: `sizeof(char)` is just another way to write 1.)

Answer (score 1):

You must fix the allocation in `allocate2d()`. If you want to allocate an array of pointers

```
arr = malloc(size * sizeof(char*));
```